# write list to csv without modules

Tags: python, export-to-csv

Now I got a list of 100 items:

```
[['A'], ['B'], ['C'], ['B'],...]
```

I need to write the list into a csv file and my expected output is like:

[image]

As I am not allowed to use any modules, most methods from the internet are not applicable.

Currently my output is like:

[image]

the code written so far is

```
 with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
        f.write('id,category\n')
        for i in range(len(list)):
            f.write(str(i+1) + ',' + str(list) + '\n')
```

How should I modify my code to reach my expected output?

Comment: The code shown has errors that would prevent it from generating _any_ output, much less what you claim it did.

Comment: Why are you not "allowed" to use modules? `csv` is part of that standard library. In any case, your question pretty much boils down to how to index a list. The problem is you keep just dumping the string representation of the list, ile. `str(list)`, which of course, gies you` [['A'], ['B'], ['C'], ['B']]`. Don't do that.

Comment: please do not use images to represent the data, edit the question and add the data in textual form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the index of the list in the loop

Try this code

```
lst = [['A'], ['B'], ['C'], ['B'], ['E'], ['F'], ['Y']]  

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('id,category\n')
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        f.write(str(i+1) + ',' + str(lst[i][0]) + '\n')
```

Output (output.csv)

```
id,category
1,A
2,B
3,C
4,B
5,E
6,F
7,Y
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you need :

```py
l = [['A'], ['B'], ['C'], ['B'], ['K'] , ['H'] ] #your list 
  
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f :
    f.write('id,kind\n')
    for ind, val in enumerate(l):
        f.write(str(ind)+','+ val[0]+'\n')
```